# Paypal sandbox window closed on subscribe button click with "create_order_error : Token Failure"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Here is the code to create subscription and user consent from paypal sandbox.

```
paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'white',
        layout: 'horizontal',
        label: 'subscribe',
        tagline: false,
    },
    createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        if( subscriber_id !== null ){
            return actions.subscription.revise(subscriber_id, {
                'plan_id': "xxxxxxxx",
            });
        }else{
            return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': "xxxxxxxx",
            });
        }
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert("Plan successfully Subscribed");
    },
    onCancel: function(data){
        alert("Payment Cancelled");
    },
    onError : function(err){
        alert("Error on payment");
    }

}).render("#paypal_button_container");
```

It successfully return subscriber ID with this url : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions

Then it open popup window for sandbox url : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/billagmt/subscriptions/I-JM3GEG2DY222/cartid and it immediately close with following "create_order_error"

```
Object { err: "TOKEN_FAILURE\nd/<@https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.label=subscribe&style.layout=horizontal&style.color=white … }
```

[image]

It was working fine before 28-Oct-2022.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the exact same issue.
The Sandbox for testing subscription is broken.
I managed to pass the "token failure" this morning and another error message was reporting that the system is not available yet because of an internal problem so I guess the issue is on paypal side and hopefuly they are working on it.
So let's just wait...